# How do I display numbers in octal notation in java?

Tags: java, loops, octal

I need to write a code for a project and part of the code needs to be able to do as follows:
Generate one random positive integer from 1 to 100, and then display all of the numbers in octal notation from 1 to the random integer.

Can someone please help me with this? (only the octal notation part)

Comment: what have you  tried so far? This is not platform to ask someone to do your homework.

Comment: I know how to do loops and generate random integers I just don't know how to do anything with octal notation so I thought id ask about it here. sorry @priyranjan

Comment: How would you convert a number to octal by hand? Start there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can print numbers in octal notation using the [`printf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)) method with the `%o` formatter:

```
System.out.printf("Number in octal notation: %o", myNumber);
```

Comment: hmm so for the 'my number' part would I just put my integers identifiers?

Comment: also if i just wanted to print them without the sentence at the start could i just write System.out.printf("%o" myNumber);

Comment: @WeirdGirlGamer yes and yes.

Answer (score 1):

You can `use Random.nextInt()` for random number and `Integer.toOctalString()` for octal conversion.

Try this out.

```java
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random random = new Random();
        int number = random.nextInt(100) + 1;
        
        for(int i = 1; i < number; i++){
            System.out.println(Integer.toOctalString(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1st generate a random number:

`int randomNum = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min, max + 1);` // in your case min=1 and max=100;

and to convert above number to octal you can use toOctalString method.

```
String myOctNumber = Integer.toOctalString(randomNum);
 System.out.println("myOctNumber = "+myOctNumber);
```